# How to make masonry grid like this?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My project has the Macy.js that making 4 columns, but I want to make a right-floating div inside the flow. I use mysql query to output blog posts.

Now I have code like this:

```
<parent container>
  <div float right></div>
  <macy container>
<? SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC ?>
<? while ... { ?>
    <post>
<? } ?>
  </macy container>
</parent container>
```

How can I make it happen as shown in my image below with js, css, php, or anything else?

[image: right floating div image]

Comment: Nice question.. I've used the magic wand to show your image... waiting for approval and it will show.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is a little tricky. Something like that:

```
<?php
     $count = 0;
     while (...) {
         $count++; ?>
         <post>
     <?php 
         if ($count == 3) { ?>
         <that right floating div>
     <?php 
         }
     }
?>
```

The general idea is to add that div as some extra post after third post (so it will be displayed in fourth column). If you want different columns amount for smaller screens you can add other divs with class to show/hide on other resoultions, just add then one or more 'if' ex.:

```
if ($count == 2) { ?>
    <that right floating div show only on tablet>
<?php }
```